# OCR library for Java: compiling tesseract on Windows 64-bit

Tags: java, dll, dependencies, 32bit-64bit, ocr

I'm using ImageJ for processing document images (business documents) and I am looking for a good OCR library to retrieve text from some regions.

Currently I am using Asprise, but the results aren't very reliable. Certain characters often get confused (0 becomes O, 8 -> B, % -> 0, ...), then there is whitespace where it's not supposed to be and thus makes a lot of trouble postprocessing this data. The images have a resolution of 1240x1754, I haven't tried a higher resolution yet, but the smallest characters I'd like to detect are 15 pixels high, so I assume the quality of the image is sufficient. (by the way, I am performing the ocr on the original image, not the binary image)

Looking at similar questions here, I noticed tesseract has often been recommeneded. Since it's written in c++ I am not sure how I can use it in Java and ImageJ.

Using Asprise, which, as far I know, is also written in c++ and just offers a Java wrapper, I can perform ocr based on a BufferedImage. So I am assume I could do the same with tesseract.

**1. How can I call tesseract functions from Java?**

**UPDATE:** I tried to use tesjeract, but when I am executing my application it crashes due to a

> UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Windows\System32\tessdll.dll: Can't find dependent libraries

I was able to successfully compile tesjeract and tesseract 2.04 and placed tessdll.dll and tesjeract.dll in c:\windows\system32 . I am using this static block to load the libraries:

```
static
{
    System.loadLibrary("tessdll");
    System.loadLibrary("tesjeract");
}
```

In case it is relevant, I am using Windows 7 64-bit.

---

**2. So how can I convert a BufferedImage into a format tesseract is able to work with?**

**SOLVED**

This is the code, if anyone is interested: (originates from [audiveris](http://audiveris.kenai.com/) )

```
private ByteBuffer imageToTiffBuffer (BufferedImage image) throws IOException
{
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ImageOutputStream     ios = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(baos);

    // Take the first suitable TIFF writer
    ImageWriter writer = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("tiff").next();
    writer.setOutput(ios);
    writer.write(image);
    ios.close();

    // allocate() doesn't work
    ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(baos.size());
    buf.put(baos.toByteArray());

    return buf;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bitness of the external libraries need to match up with your JVM.  Since tesjeract is the lowest common denominator, you'll need to use the 32 bit JVM.

Answer (score 1):

You could look at [audiveris](http://audiveris.kenai.com), a Java OMR package that I believe uses Tesseract for the text portions of sheets.

Comment: thanks! I found a method to convert the image for tesseract there.

Answer (score 1):

There are two Java wrappers for Tesseract 2.04 that you may want to take a look: [Tess4J](http://tess4j.sf.net) and [Tesjeract](http://code.google.com/p/tesjeract/).